# Showing NP-completeness of a graph problem with vertex capacities

Tags: graphs, np-complete, reductions, np

The problem:
Given an undirected graph G = {V, E}, a source-vertex s, and each vertex having a "capacity" between 0 and |V|, is there a tree which covers all vertices and does not extend from a vertex more times than its capacity allows, while also not covering every edge? Demonstrate that it is NP-complete.

An example graph with a source can be seen below, and an example solution, with each vertex not having more edges extend from it than its capacity would allow.

[image]

While showing it is in NP is trivial, performing a reduction from a known NP-complete problem to show this problem is NP-hard is where I am having some difficulty. I am having some suspicions that reducing a problem like vertex cover might prove easiest, but I am quite stuck here.

Comment: What does "extend from a vertex" mean?

Comment: @Nathaniel I might not know the correct terminology here, but I mean that edges in the tree can start at the given vertex. In the example above.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not understand your explication, nor how the example illustrates that notion.

Comment: Try reducing from Hamiltonian path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform each instance of the hamiltonian cycle problem (finding a cycle that visits each vertex exactly once) into an instance of your problem.
Given a hamiltonian cycle problem with a graph $G=(V,E)$, you can apply the reduction described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1290804/1127243) to turn the graph $G$ into a graph $f(G)$ for the hamiltonian path problem, which is the same as your problem if you restrict the capacity of each vertex to 1. This reduction also gives you a source.
You can map the set of instances of the hamiltonian cycle problem to a subset of the instances of your problem, solving these in polynomial time would solve the hamiltonian cycle problem. This proves your problem is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard.

Comment: Yup, that's definitely it. I'll look into the reduction, but this definitely put me on the right track!

Comment: Also, while cleaving the vertex v you add a new edge v-v' which will not be used in the solution to your problem (restricting the capacity to 1 and keeping in mind you have to start from s and end in t), thus also satisfying the condition that not all edges should be covered.